# Integrate openstack Swift storage with ceph

Tags: amazon-s3, openstack-swift, ceph

I am new with Software defined storage. I was working on possible ways of integration of different object storage implementations like AWS S3, Openstack Swift with Ceph.

**I am wondering if I can use ceph API calls to store objects in Openstack swift?**
The [document](http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/) here specifies that I can use Swift APIs to store objects in ceph (OSDs), but is it possible the other way around?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exaclty. Ceph Rados Gateway is a full replacement of Swift Object storage with some missing functionality as described here.
http://docs.ceph.com/docs/master/radosgw/swift/

To make it clear, in order to store objects in Ceph Cluster you should just setup Rados Gateway and that's it. You will have two options to operate either using Swift API or S3 API.

Rados Gateway also supports S3 API to store objects. You can even configure RGW to access containers like S3 bucket subdomains. Ex: #bucketname#.s3.example.com